# TypeScript: Find Key Value in Object

Tags: typescript

I have an object like

```
const myObj = {
  policy : {
            title: "policy title",
            page : "/pageOne"
         },
  purchase : {
            title: "purchase title",
            page : "/pageTwo"
         }
}
```

I need to search through this object and find where page is "/pageTwo" and return not just the title but also the key (ie purchase)

Is there a simple way to do this in TS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const myObj = {
  policy: {
    title: "policy title",
    page: "/pageOne"
  },
  purchase: {
    title: "purchase title",
    page: "/pageTwo"
  }
}

const found = Object.entries(myObj).find(([, {page}]) => page === "/pageTwo")
console.log(found)
```

[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns an array of `[key, value]` pairs, so `Object.entries(myObj)` would be

```js
[
  ["policy", {title: "policy title", page: "/pageOne"}],
  ["purchase", {title: "purchase title", page: "/pageTwo"}]
]
```

Then, find the entry where the value's `page` property is `"/pageTwo"` using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).